# Not able to render image using TinyMCE in ASP.Net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, browser, tinymce

I have a word press like web site with tinyMCE Editor embedded into where one can add text, images to their websites. But the problem is when someone tries to upload the image via tinyMCE "upload image" button then image gets loaded to the tinyMCE editor but when user saves the configuration and Now when the user visits the actual web site, the image is broken.

```
Step 1: Add image to TinyMCE Editor (parent website)

     2. Save the configurations

     3. Go to the actual web site (created one) and see the change
```

The weird part if the above 3 process is repeated for example 10 times with different images by running the Parent (word press) website in IE, Chrome and Mozilla then all of a sudden in the (created website) 2-3 times in Mozilla the image renders properly, 2-3 times in IE image renders properly and it just never renders properly in Chrome. So basically I tried running the parent web site (word press)  in all three browsers and the saw the behaviour of (created website) and all three browsers are showing erratic behaviour.

Chrome Error:

[image]

Also, When I inspect the image element of the page (created website) the `src` format keeps on changing.

sometimes it is `base 64: src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw....`

sometimes it is `<img id="img" src="blob:http://localhost:5271/68b294bc-3b0a-415f-943b-571f4c65206c" alt="">`

sometimes it is `<img id="img" src="blob:cabd2fd9-515f-4b46-90ab-2f33dd9bc241" alt="">` ----> (NO HTTP)

I am using tinyMCE `<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>`

I don't know what code snippet to put please guide me. If any code snippet will help finding the issue then please let me know. I am totally lost here. I can put the JS code or the cshtml code if it helps. I wish I knew a better way to ask this question. :(

```
function InitTinyForSpecificElement(elementName) {
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "#" + elementName,
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: [
            "autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern table fullscreen imagetools"
        ],
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | fontselect | bold italic underline strikethrough | subscript superscript | forecolor backcolor | link unlink",
        toolbar2: 'preview fullscreen  code | myInsertImage image | table | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | outdent indent',
        toolbar_items_size: 'small',
        image_advtab: true,
        paste_data_images: true,
        setup: function (ed) {
            ed.addButton('myInsertImage', {
                title: 'Insert Image',
                image: '../../Content/Images/insert-image-icon.png',
                onclick: function () {
                    tinyMceElementId = elementName;
                    $('#uploadImageIntoTinyMce').trigger('click');
                }
            });
```

**EDIT:** 
So this time I added two images in chrome. Because of abnormal behviour in the (created site) one image got rendered properly and another image got broken. So, out of curiosity I simply opened the same (created web site)in Mozilla but I do not see even a single image. So, I inspected the empty element to atleast find two img tags (even though none of them is visible on UI) but I could find just one img tag. Firstly, Chrome should show two images. But it showed only one. And now atleast I should see the same behaviour in Mozilla but its not showing any image on UI and even on inspecting atleast two placeholders should be there but that I found only one palceholder. I HAVE CLEARED CACHE AND ALL AND BROWSING HISTORY. Below is the screenshot
Chrome Screenshot

Chrome Inspect element with `two img` tags:

[image]

Mozilla Screenshot with just `one img` tags

[image]

Empty Mozilla UI

[image]

Broken Chrome UI

[image]